# How does a thread in NPTL exit?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, pthreads, system-calls, glibc

I'm curious how a single NPTL thread exits, from implementation perspective.

What I understand about *glibc-2.30*'s implementation are:

1. NPTL thread is built on top of light weight process on Linux, with additional information stored in pthread object on user stack, to keep track of NPTL specific information such as join/detach status and returned object's pointer.
2. when a NPTL thread is finished, it is gone for good, only the user stack (and hence) pthread object is left to be collected (to be joined by other threads), unless it is a detached, in which case that space is directly freed.
3. `_exit()` syscall kills all threads in a thread group.
4. the user function that [`pthread_create()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/glibc/glibc-2.30/source/nptl/pthread_create.c#L625) takes in is actually wrapped into another function [`start_thread()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/glibc/glibc-2.30/source/nptl/pthread_create.c#L378), which does some preparation before running the user function, and some cleaning up afterwards.

Questions are:

1. At the end of the wrapper function [`start_thread()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/glibc/glibc-2.30/source/nptl/pthread_create.c#L378), there are the following comment and code:

   ```
   /* We cannot call '_exit' here.  '_exit' will terminate the process.

    The 'exit' implementation in the kernel will signal when the
    process is really dead since 'clone' got passed the CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID
    flag.  The 'tid' field in the TCB will be set to zero.

    The exit code is zero since in case all threads exit by calling
    'pthread_exit' the exit status must be 0 (zero).  */
    __exit_thread ();
   ```

   but [`__exit_thread()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/glibc/glibc-2.30/source/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/exit-thread.h#L26) seems to do syscall `_exit()` anyways:

   ```
    static inline void __attribute__ ((noreturn, always_inline, unused))
    __exit_thread (void)
    {
      /* some comments here */
      while (1)
        {
          INTERNAL_SYSCALL_DECL (err);
          INTERNAL_SYSCALL (exit, err, 1, 0);
        }
    }
   ```

   so I'm confused here, since it shouldn't really do syscall `_exit()` because it will terminate all threads.
2. [`pthread_exit()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/glibc/glibc-2.30/source/nptl/pthread_exit.c#L24) should terminate a single thread, so it should do something similar to what the wrapper `start_thread()` does in the end, however it calls [`__do_cancel()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/glibc/glibc-2.30/source/nptl/pthreadP.h#L302), and TBH I am lost in tracing down that function. It does not seem to be related to the above `__exit_thread()`, nor does it call `_exit()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm confused here, since it shouldn't really do syscall _exit()

The confusion here stems from mixing `exit` system call with `_exit` libc routine (there is no `_exit` system call on Linux).

The former terminates current Linux thread (as intended).

The latter (confusingly) doesn't execute `exit` system call. Rather, it executes `exit_group` system call, which terminates *all* threads.

> thread_exit() should terminate a single thread

It does, indirectly. It unwinds current stack (similar to `siglongjmp`), performing control transfer to the point where `cleanup_jmp_buf` was set up. And that was in `start_thread`.

After the control transfer, `start_thread` cleans up resources, and calls `__exit_thread` to actually terminate the thread.

Comment: That explains everything, thank you! I revisited the man page `man 2 _exit`, and the Notes section says 'In glibc up to version 2.3, the `_exit()` wrapper function invoked the kernel system call of the same name.  Since glibc 2.3, the wrapper function invokes  `exit_group`(2),  in order to terminate all of the threads in a process.  (The raw `_exit()` system call terminates only the calling thread.)'. Is it an outdated description, or there was a system call named `_exit` up to glibc 2.3? The fact that there is a `_exit` page in `man` section 2 seems a bit weird.

Comment: @QnA I agree: I think `_exit` should be moved to section 3, as it describes the `libc` function and not a system call. Feel free to file a bug.